# Chrome Extension: window.innerWidth = 0 ? // bonus: maximizing window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am creating a chrome extension to easily swap between different screen sizes (in order to test responsive design). Although this already exists, I figured it would be a good excercise.

I am running into 2 problems:

1. When I try to calculate the size of the frame (window.width - window.innerWidth), window.innerWidth displays as 0 in the console log.
2. I cannot find any way to easily maximize the window. I could resize to screen.width and screen.height, but that's not really maximizing. What are my options? The developer site and google itself didn't return much usable info.

Here's some of my code:

```
function resize(win){
window = win;
frameWidth = window.width - window.innerWidth;
frameHeight = window.height - window.innerHeight;
console.log(window.innerWidth);
...
}
```

Comment: Are you accessing `window` of your extension's scope or of a tab's scope ?

Comment: @ldiqual Uhm I have no clue but I'm going to assume extension as the result is 0... how do I change that?

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing your background page, that's why you have width/height = 0. You have to access the current window.

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
  // You can modify some width/height here
}
```

Window properties are described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#type-Window). For instance, you can modify width/height by using:

```
w.width = 300;
w.height = 200;
```

Comment: I actually tried that. As a matter of fact, I use getCurrent to resize the window (which works), it's just that it resizes the outer window, and I want to set the inner window size to be exactly the size I need. I will upload the entire sourcecode when I get home (it's on my desktop), I hope you don't mind taking a peak then.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight:

var width = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth;

But you may have this right and the problem you might be running into is trying to calculate the width from your background page.  The innerWidth from your background page is 0 because it's an invisible 0-size window.

To get the actual outerWidth (or innerWidth), you need to execute the code in the visible window in question.  You can do this with a content script if one is active, or you can create a new HTML page in your extension, load it in a tab in the window, have it do the calculations and send the data back to your background page with sendRequest.

Comment: Hi

Sounds like you're right about the 0-value return. However, I didn't quite understand the following explanation completely; would you mind explaining in more detail or pointing me in the right direction?

To be clear, the idea of the plugin is resizing the window for responsive layout testing - so it will be used a lot, and needs to be fast as lightning. Will this work?